# Is there any library for OAuth registration on .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, oauth

everybody:) I need to implement OAuth registration on my project, but I don't have a time to learn whole protocol, and write low-level code. Is there any library for .NET that can make it easier? I wanna make OAuth registration for Facebook and some not so famous portals. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ASP.NET MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) project templates include user registration using OAuth authentication servers out-of-the-box for Facebook, Google, Twitter.

Aside from that, you can try looking at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)